# Passing Data from a Data Table in the feature file to my step definitions (js)

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

I'm trying to pass Data from a table into a feature file and then finally onto my java script step-definitions, shown below.

```
Scenario: XX | Basket Tests: Cover Type | Building + no bundle + HE 

Given I open the page with the url "http://localhost:3000" and route "/basket"
When I click the button <coverTypeID>
And I click the button <bundleID>
Then I see the result <expectedResult>

| id |             url              | coverTypeID    | bundleID | elementID | expectedResult |
| 1  | http://localhost:3000/basket | coverTypeId101 | NoBundle | null      |                |
| 2  | http://localhost:3000/basket | coverTypeId101 | NoBundle | checkbox1 |                | 
| 3  | http://localhost:3000/basket | coverTypeId101 | NoBundle | checkbox2 |                | 
| 4  | http://localhost:3000/basket | coverTypeId101 | NoBundle | checkbox3 |                | 
| 5  | http://localhost:3000/basket | coverTypeId101 | NoBundle | checkbox4 |                |
```

Is my Feature file, i used to pass data using strings however now i am using the data table it doesn't identify the scenario when the tests run.

```
    When("I click the button <coverTypeID>", (buttonID, next) => {

    driver.findElement(By.id(buttonID)).then(pageElement => {                           /////////////////////////////////////////////
        driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(pageElement), 10000).then(async () => {      //This is to click a button using elementID//
         await driver.sleep(3000);                                                      /////////////////////////////////////////////
         pageElement.click();
         next();
         })
         .catch(ex => {
            console.log(ex.message, ex.stack)
         });
    }).catch(ex => {console.log(ex.message, ex.stack)});
});
```

**The error i'm getting is that the tests are undefined as the scenario doesn't match the step definition properly because of the usage of the table titles**

I've looked at using Regular Expressions however i'm not sure what type of data the data table passes when executing, any guidance would be of use, i've went through a bunch of different questions and none quite seem to answer mine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i'd like to avoid regular expression if i could because the aim is to make the code as readable as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found the solution, rather than expecting the title of the data table i referred back to using {string}

```
When("I click the button {string}", (buttonID, next) => {
```

Then in the data table i realised the mistake i was making was simply not adding quotation marks to make the data into string format.

```
Examples:
| id | coverTypeID      | bundleID       | elementID   | 
| 1  | "coverTypeId101" | "moreDetails1" | "checkbox2" |
```

By doing this the feature now sucessfully pulls data from the feature file into the JS file.